# Choice parameter having strings having space

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to write a groovy script for a job to have a choice parameter. One of the choices would a string with space in between ( i.e 'test env' ). Is there any way we can achieve that ?

Current code
parameters {
choice(name: 'environment_name', description: 'The environment name',choices: 'test\ntest env')
}

Is there any way we can achieve this in groovy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a list for `choices`:

```
parameters {
   choice(name: 'environment_name',
          description: 'The environment name',
          choices: ['test','test env'])
}
```

Comment: @Ayan, keep in mind, Jenkins is Unix based and it does not play well with spaces much, so you must quote all variables which might contain spaces. Search S/O for posts regarding single/double quotes usage and groovy vs shell interpolation in pipelines as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.